# python beautiful soup web crawling with json

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup, request, web-crawler

I'm new to beautifulsoup in python and I"m trying to extract certain information from a website. In detail, the url and the title.

I use beautifulsoup to extract the json which I successfully did but I´m unsure about the next steps, how to get the url and title

I did not manage to extract the desired information yet. I hope you guys can help me out

That is my logic so far:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import urllib.request

session = requests.Session()
session.cookies.get_dict()
url = 'http://www.citydis.com/'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1)     AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
response = session.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
metaConfig = soup.find("meta",  property="configuration")
metaConfigTxt = metaConfig["content"]
csrf = json.loads(metaConfigTxt)["pageToken"]


jsonUrl = "https://www.citydis.com/s/results.json?&q=London&     customerSearch=1&page=0"
headers.update({'X-Csrf-Token': csrf})
response = session.get(jsonUrl, headers=headers)
print(response.content)
```

And that is the output:

```
b'{"searchResults":{"customer":null,"signupUrl":"\\/signup\\/?pos=activityCard","isMobile":false,"tours":[{"tourId":5459,"title":"Ticket f\\u00fcr Coca-Cola London Eye 4D-Erlebnis","url":"https:\\/\\/www.getyourguide.de\\/london-l57\\/ohne-anstehen-edf-london-eye-4d-erlebnis-t5459\\/","price":{"original":"27,10\\u00a0\\u20ac","min":"27,10\\u00a0\\u20ac","type":"individual"},"horizontalImageUrl":"https:\\/\\/cdn.getyourguide.com\\/img\\/tour_img-412120-70.jpg","horizontalAlternativeImageUrl":"https:\\/\\/cdn.getyourguide.com\\/img\\/tour_img-412120-85.jpg","verticalImageUrl":"https:\\/\\/cdn.getyourguide.com\\/img\\/tour_img-412120-92.jpg","mobileImageUrl":"https:\\/\\/cdn.getyourguide.com\\/img\\/tour_img-412120-53.jpg","horizontalSlimImageUrl":"https:\\/\\/cdn.getyourguide.com\\/img\\/tour_img-412120-67.jpg","highlightedDetailedImageUrl":"https:\\/\\/cdn.getyourguide.com\\/img\\/tour_img-412120-91.jpg","smallDescription":"Sehen Sie London aus einer anderen Perspektive vom London Eye aus und genie\\u00dfen Sie beim neuen 4D-Erlebnis einen bahnbrechenden 3D-Film mit\\u2026","description":"Sehen Sie London aus einer anderen Perspektive vom London Eye aus und genie\\u00dfen Sie beim neuen 4D-Erlebnis einen bahnbrechenden 3D-Film mit spektakul\\u00e4ren Spezialeffekten, einschlie\\u00dflich Wind und Nebel. Genie\\u00dfen Sie au\\u00dferdem bevorzugten Einlass am Eingang.","isBestseller":false,"isFeatured":false,"languageIds":[],"hasDeal":false,"dealMaxPercentage":0,"isBoostedNewTour":false,"hasBanner":false,"hasRibbon":false,"priceTag":true,"detailsLink":false,"isCertifiedPartner":true,"hasFencedDiscountDeal":false,"hasFreeCancellation":false,"hasRating":true,"averageRating":"4,5","totalRating":1633,"totalRatingTitle":"1633 Bewertungen","averageRatingClass":"45","ratingLink":"","ratingStyleModifier":"","ratingStarsClasses":"","ratingTitle":"Bewertung: 4,5 von 5","hasDuration":true,"duration":"40 Minuten","displayAbstract":true,"displayDuration":true,"displayDate":false,"displayWishlist":false,"displayRemoveButton":false,"hasDiscountedRecommendation":false,"hideImage":false,"isSkipTheLine":false,"likelyToSellOutBadge":true,"isPromoted":false,"isSpecialOffer":false,"experiments":{"hasRatingsExperiment":false,"numericRatingLabel":"Basierend auf 1633 Bewertungen","verticalImageForPriceSegmentation":"https:\\/\\/cdn.getyourguide.com\\/img\\/tour_img-412120-150.jpg"},"id":"searchResults","activityCardVersion":"horizontal","limit":false,"likelyToSellOutExperiment":{"deviceDetector":{}},"hasNumericReviews":true,"resultSetPosition":0,"activityCardStyle":"plain","highlightedOrientation":"horizontal"},{"tourId":51268,"title":"Bustransfer: Flughafen Stansted - Stadtzentrum London","url":"https:\\/\\/www.getyourguide.de\\/london-l57\\/bustransfer-flughafen-stansted-stadtzentrum-london-t51268\\/","price":{"original":"9,43\\u00a0\\u20ac","min":"9,43\\u00a0\\u20ac","type":"individual"},"horizontalImageUrl":"https:\\/\\/cdn.getyourguide.com\\/img\\/tour_img-451822-70.jpg","horizontalAlternativeImageUrl":"https:\\/\\/cdn.getyourguide.com\\/img\\/tour_img-451822-85.jpg","verticalImageUrl":"https:\\/\\/cdn.getyourguide.com\\/img\\/tour_img-451822-92.jpg","mobileImageUrl":"https:\\/\\/cdn.getyourguide.com\\/img\\/tour_img-451822-53.jpg","horizontalSlimImageUrl":"https:\\/\\/cdn.getyourguide.com\\/img\\/tour_img-451822-67.jpg","highlightedDetailedImageUrl":"https:\\/\\/cdn.getyourguide.com\\/img\\/tour_img-451822-91.jpg","smallDescription":"Beginnen oder beenden Sie Ihren Aufenthalt in London mit dem praktischen Bustransfer zwischen dem Flughafen Stansted und dem Stadtzentrum London.\\u2026","description":"Beginnen oder beenden Sie Ihren Aufenthalt in London mit dem praktischen Bustransfer zwischen dem Flughafen Stansted und dem Stadtzentrum London. Sparen Sie sich die Fahrt mit \\u00f6ffentlichen Verkehrsmitteln und erreichen Sie London schnell und bequem.","isBestseller":false,"isFeatured":false,"languageIds":[],"hasDeal":false,"dealMaxPercentage":0,"isBoostedNewTour":false,"hasBanner":false,"hasRibbon":false,"priceTag":true,"detailsLink":false,"isCertifiedPartner":false,"hasFencedDiscountDeal":false,"hasFreeCancellation":true,"hasRating":true,"averageRating":"4,4","totalRating":541,"totalRatingTitle":"541 Bewertungen","averageRatingClass":"45","ratingLink":"","ratingStyleModifier":"","ratingStarsClasses":"","ratingTitle":"Bewertung: 4,4 von 5","hasDuration":true,"duration":"60 Minuten \\u2013 90 Minuten","displayAbstract":true,"displayDuration":true,"displayDate":false,"displayWishlist":false,"displayRemoveButton":false,"hasDiscountedRecommendation":false,"hideImage":false,"isSkipTheLine":false,"likelyToSellOutBadge":true,"isPromoted":false,"isSpecialOffer":false,"experiments":{"hasRatingsExperiment":false,"numericRatingLabel":"Basierend auf 541 Bewertungen","verticalImageForPriceSegmentation":"https:\\/\\/cdn.getyourguide.com\\/img\\/tour_img-451822-150.jpg"}
```

What I would like to get out is the title and url only. For example:

```
title":"Ticket f\\u00fcr Coca-Cola London Eye 4D-Erlebnis","url":"https:\\/\\/www.getyourguide.de\\/london-l57\\/ohne-anstehen-edf-london-eye-4d-erlebnis-t5459
```

Any feedback much appreciated

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the feedback I was able to solve the problem.

I´m now able to get the desired result but now I have the issue that I´m just getting one result back instead of all available:

```
js_dict = (json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8')))

url = (js_dict['searchResults']["tours"][0]["url"])
print(url)

title = (js_dict['searchResults']["tours"][0]["title"])
print(title)

price = (js_dict['searchResults']["tours"][0]["price"]["original"])
print(price)
```

Output is the following one:

```
https://www.citydis.de/london-l57/ohne-anstehen-edf-london-eye-4d-erlebnis-t5459/
Ticket für Coca-Cola London Eye 4D-Erlebnis
27,10 €
```

I would like to get all the titles, prices and urls back of the sightseeings which are in the JSON. I tried with the for loop but somehow it does not work.

Any feedback appreciated

**UPDATE 2**

Found a solution:

```
jsonUrl = "https://www.citydis.com/s/results.json?&q=London& customerSearch=1&page=0"
headers.update({'X-Csrf-Token': csrf})
response = session.get(jsonUrl, headers=headers)
js_dict = (json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8')))

for item in js_dict:
    headers = js_dict['searchResults']["tours"]
    prices = js_dict['searchResults']["tours"]
    urls = js_dict['searchResults']["tours"]


for title, price, url in zip(headers, prices, urls):

    title_final = title.get("title")
    url_final = url.get("url")
    price_final = price.get("price")["original"]
    print("Header: " + title_final + " | " + "Deeplink: " + url_final + " | " + "Price: " + price_final)
```

Comment: So you want to get title and url from output json ?

Comment: Why dont you `json.loads` your response , and get the keys you want ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string `response.content` is indeed the JSON output. You could import the `json` module, and parse the JSON with a statement like

```
js_dict = json.loads(response.content)
```

This will parse the JSON and produce a Python dictionary in `js_dict`. You can then use standard dictionary subscripting techniques to access and display the fields of interest.

Because this is such a common requirement, the response object has a `json` method that will do this decoding for you. You could, therefore, simply write

```
js_dict = response.json()
```

Comment: Appreciate it. Updated my post. Could you help me out one more time?

Comment: I'd love to be able to help, but the JSON string you show doesn't appear to be the Python representation of a valid JSON string. When I run your code, `requests` tells me that there's no such site, and `citydis.com` isn't a registered domain name. Sorry.

Comment: In which case can you write up the solution? It's perfectly acceptable to answer your own questions!

Comment: You save my life, you are genius!

Comment: You seriously overrate my abilities, but I'm very glad you were able to solve your problem!